# How to manually change <option> select and be included in POST request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I am manually selecting the value for class .fare:

```
options_fare = '<option value='Z'>Select a fare</option><option value='All fare'>All fare</option>'

$contextualDiv.children('.fare').html(options_fare);
$contextualDiv.find('.fare option:eq(1)').attr('selected', 'selected').trigger('change');
$contextualDiv.children('.fare').attr('disabled', true);
```

However, when I try to post the result through an AJAX call. The value of fare is []. What am I missing?

Comment: Your `options_fare` string has unescaped quotes; it is syntactically invalid

Comment: wrap `value` and `text` in `''` instead

Comment: sorry. options_fare is indeed in ' '. I just copied it in incorrect. The issue is something else that I'm not seeing.

Comment: It's still incorrect, but lets assume it's not, as you're getting to the ajax call without syntax errors in the console, cause you did check the console, right ?

Comment: perhaps you should put your ajax code as well

Comment: yes. I originally had it as a selection drop down for the user. That worked. However, it broke when I used jquery to manually manipulate the selection value.

Comment: Note that you now have a select with one single option, and that select is disabled, and won't be posted on  a regular form submit

Comment: I don't want the user to changed the manual select. is there an alternate way of doing that?

Comment: I don't think the disabled is the issue. I commented that out and it still doesn't submit in the post request.

Comment: We can't possibly know what the issue is, we haven't seen the markup nor the code that posts the data?

Comment: Does `$contextualDiv.children('.fare').val('All fare')` work as intended?

Comment: @adeneo Right.. fixed!